# Is traffic between google app engine instances compressed automatically?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a couple of Apps, one acting as client and another one as a REST server.

In order to improve performance I decided to use gzip, but after applying it and looking at the server logs I see no difference in the size of the data being transmitted.

**1. Call performed from a REST Client on my local machine (without gzip):**

2012-09-05 23:43:23.935 /rest/RatePeriod 200 3544ms 942kb Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)

**2. Call performed using gzip**

2012-09-05 23:42:10.466 /rest/RatePeriod 200 3776ms 22kb gzip

**3. Call performed from one app to another (without accept gzip headers)**

2012-09-05 22:44:11.691 /rest/RatePeriod/ 200 3489ms 22kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: s~XXXXXX)

Is some kind of compression applied automatically by GAE in the communication between instances?

Answer (score 2):

GAE automatically gzips requests if it detects a client that supports it.  According to this SO question, urlfetch implicitly sets the accept-encoding: gzip header.

[appengine, urlfetch, and the content-length header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590844/appengine-urlfetch-and-the-content-length-header), in which case, seeing compression applied makes sense.

Comment: As far as I know it is not enough to set accept-encoding, you also have to set the User-Agent header to "gzip".

Comment: Actually, you don't have to set either if App Engine recognizes your user agent and determines that it supports gzip.  Setting those two headers will force App Engine to use gzip.